# How to save the contents of "Konsole" terminal in KDE

Tags: linux, io-redirection, kde, konsole

I want to know is there any way to save the contents (i.e, commands and stdout together) of Konsole terminal in KDE desktop as in Xfce4-terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `File>Save output as...`